# SAPUI5 Can't run local Fiori Application properly from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

We used this tutorial to start developing Fiori apps with VS Code:

https://blogs.sap.com/2020/07/16/developing-sap-fiori-app-using-sap-fiori-tools-in-visual-studio-code/

Everything works fine so far, except the connection to the backend services. When we want to start the application locally we get the following error by getting the OData metadata.

[image: Console Screenshot]

Our server config in ui5-local.yaml:

[image: ui5-local.yaml]

Before switching to VS Code we used the local WebIDE which worked fine. So I guess there is no configuration on the SAP system which blocks the request.

Did anyone face the same issue and has a solution for us? I searched online and couldn't find anything that fits our problem.

Thanks a lot for any hints.

Comment: Would it work if you set ignore cert errors to true, as per the flag in your yaml file?

Comment: I tried it already and it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have some corporate proxy which needs to be configured in npm?

Comment: Yes we have a corporate proxy and it is already configured in npm. I already needed this to install all the packages.

Answer (score -1):

try this npm install ui5-middleware-proxy-basicauth --save-dev

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but it doesn't change anything. It is still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Are you by any chance in corporate network which uses Self-Signed Certificate. If so npm might fail. Change the `ignoreCertError: true` and give it a try.